# Having trouble triggering MassTransit consumer in xunit test

Tags: autofac, xunit, masstransit

I'm having 2 issues trying to unit test some code that uses MassTransit saga state machines and consumers. I'm using Autofac as a container and xUnit as a test framework.

I've got an example unit test [here](https://github.com/jeremy-skippen/masstransit-autofac-xunit-problem/blob/main/ExampleTest.cs) that illustrates both problems.

1. When using just an Autofac container to set up my SagaStateMachine and Consumer, I can't assert that my state machine or consumer have consumed any messages - it seems as though they're not connected to the test bus.
   (test `ExampleTest_AutofacOnly`)

   I can get around this by introducing a `ServiceCollection` to the test and resolving the harnesses from the `ServiceProvider` instead of the `IContainer` but this feels like double handling.
   (test `ExampleTest_AutofacAndServiceProvider`)
2. I cannot trigger my consumer using `InMemoryTestHarness.Bus.Publish()` (but I can trigger the state machine). What's really irritating is that I can trigger my state machine using `InMemoryTestHarness.Bus.Publish()`, and then the state machine can trigger the consumer when it handles the event.
   (tests `ExampleTest2_AutofacOnly` & `ExampleTest2_AutofacAndServiceProvider`)

**EDIT**

(2) doesn't seem to be a problem any more after I've commented out some lines. The equivalent lines in my example are:

```
// In my actual unit test the code below causes the test to fail
var state = sagaHarness.Sagas.Select(s => s.CorrelationId == correlationId).Single();
Assert.Equal("Progress state machine", state.Saga.Message);

// 4. Trigger the second consumer
await testHarness.Bus.Publish(new ExampleMessage2
{
    CorrelationId = correlationId,
    Message = "Trigger consumer",
});

// 5. Check that ExampleMessage has been published and received
Assert.True(await testHarness.Published.Any<ExampleMessage2>(m => m.Context.CorrelationId == correlationId));
Assert.True(await testHarness.Consumed.Any<ExampleMessage2>(m => m.Context.CorrelationId == correlationId));
Assert.True(await consumer2Harness.Consumed.Any<ExampleMessage2>(m => m.Context.CorrelationId == correlationId));
```

When I get the saga instance with `sagaHarness.Sagas.Select()` it prevents the message published below it from being consumed.